# Conflicting dependency error while trying to install available updates

Tags: android, eclipse

I clicked on Help->Check for Updates and I got a list :

```
Android DDMS                                         16.0.1.v201112150204-238534  
Android Development Tools                                16.0.1.v201112150204-238534  
Android Hierarchy Viewer                                 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534  
Eclipse SDK                                               3.6.2.M20110210-1200
```

But when I try to update any one of them at a time or all of them, i get errors similar to below each time. For example, when i try to update the Eclipse SDK, i get the following error:

> Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
>   Software being installed: Eclipse SDK 3.6.2.M20110210-1200
>   (org.eclipse.sdk.ide 3.6.2.M20110210-1200)   Software currently
>   installed: Shared profile 1.0.0.1284044083462
>   (SharedProfile_SDKProfile 1.0.0.1284044083462)   Only one of the
>   following can be installed at once: 
>       Eclipse SDK 3.6.1.M20100909-0800 (org.eclipse.sdk.ide 3.6.1.M20100909-0800)
>       Eclipse SDK 3.6.2.M20110210-1200 (org.eclipse.sdk.ide 3.6.2.M20110210-1200)   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Shared profile 1.0.0.1284044083462 (SharedProfile_SDKProfile 1.0.0.1284044083462)
>       To: org.eclipse.sdk.ide [3.6.1.M20100909-0800]

Please assist. Thanks!

Jumana

Answer (score 1):

You are using shared Eclipse instance. It means the Eclipse itself is read-only, your account doesn't have privilege to write the folder of Eclipse. Then your Android updating wants to modify the base Eclipse itself(from 3.6 to 3.7).

You can move/copy the Eclipse into a folder can be written. Or use another user to update your android plug-ins who has privilege to modify the base Eclipse.

Comment: Kane, if I uncheck the "Eclipse SDK" and tick the rest of the 3 updates, Im still unable to go ahead with the installation. a similar error shows up. So it can't be the problem with the Eclipse SDK alone can it?

Comment: @Jumana, because ADT 16.0 requires new version of GMF that requires Eclipse 3.7. It's a transitive dependency.

Comment: Kane,just want make clear/point out few things before i do anything drastic...1) I'm only updating 3.6.1 to 3.6.2 not 3.7 2)I was doing all the updation with a windows admin privileged user itself. SO will moving/copying to another folder help? 3) By moving/copying, you mean re installing eclipse in another destination right?